# Mediawiki css code in cell

Tags: css, mediawiki

There's a way to use a long css code in a cell table?
That's what I'm trying to do:

This code 
`style="background: azuros; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #00FFFF, #ffffff); background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, #00FFFF, #ffffff); background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #00FFFF, #ffffff); background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #00FFFF, #ffffff);}"`

is pretty long and I have to write it everytime I need the cell colored in that way, so I've tried to put in Common.css, but I can't find a way to call it in table format.

This is a page that must use that code
http://shopheroesitalia.com/index.php?title=Prova

Comment: I don't need in every <td>, but only when I need it

Comment: No one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can put classes on a MediaWiki table, as seen in the [official documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#class.3D.22wikitable.22). It would look like this:

```
{| class="myclassname" 
...
|}
```

And in `MediaWiki:Common.css`, just style it however you'd like:

```
.myclassname td {
    background: azuros;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #00FFFF, #ffffff);
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Leo, but I'm looking for a more flexible solution. I need this color only in  few <td>, not in everyone

Comment: MediaWiki also support html markup for tables, so you could use normal html tags, and add a class to your cells. Or you could use a template for those specific cells.